# How many units are in the lengths of its diagonals

Tags: absolute-value

The way I solved the problem is to change the equation to $|x+2|=1-|y-3|$, and then square both sides. But I don't think it is the right way to solve the problem. I hope someone can either give me a hint or show me how to solve the problem.

> $|x+2|+|y-3|=1$ is an equation for a square. How many units are in the lengths of its diagonals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same as
$|x|+|y| = 1$,
but shifted so that
its center is at
$(-2, 3)$.

This is the square
with vertices
$(1, 0), (0, 1),
(-1, 0), (0, -1)$.

The diagonals are
$(1, 0)$ to $(-1, 0)$
and
$(0, 1)$ to $(0, -1)$
and their lengths
are each $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum difference of the $x$s comes when $y=3$ so the second absolute value is zero.  That means $|x+2|=1$, which gives $x=-3,-1$.  One diagonal is from $(-3,3)$ to $(-1,3)$ and is $2$ units long.   The other diagonal is along the line $x=-2$.